# Telegram bot sending error "Something went wrong, please try again" after message

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Output

```
aaaaaa
Something went wrong, please try again.
```

Code:

```
import telegram

    TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxY"
        bot = telegram.Bot(TOKEN)
        print("Bot connected!")
        chat_id = "@News"

        texto = 'aaaaaa'
        bot.send_message(chat_id, texto, parse_mode='markdown', disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

requirements.txt
python-telegram-bot

How can I fix this?

Comment: I am also getting same issue, have you found any solution?

Comment: Any progress? I have same problem. When I revoke the Bot token, it will fine for a while but then, it's giving same error. I've tried 2 different methods are Requests and python-telegram-bot but none of them fixed this.

Comment: As posted here, it doesn't look like a valid Python program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess someone scraped your bot token from a public repository and tried to steal your bot. Please, do not save your bot token in a public repository!

Solution: Revoke your token and don't save it in a public repository.

Comment: @diegooli do you save your bot-token somewhere in public? Try to send a message to your bot. What do you receive?

Comment: was as public on github, thanks!! it works for a while without shows the error

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue. Then I revoked my bot token through BotFather and so far it's been back to normal.

Comment: I would like to point that this solution is only temporary, since I started getting the same issue today, so probably I'll have to code something in order to revoke my token id every once in a while.